# Need to print top three values in console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I just found elements (around 100 float values) via XPath and printed them on console using System.Out.. Now I need to sort them and print top three values from them. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the SO-community. If the given answers do not help you, and if you wonder why people down-voted your question I suggest you add the information that people need to answer you properly. It is unclear if you have trouble with sorting, with selecting three from a list or with finding the float value in the HTML. If would help if you could specify your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Since yo are using SeleniumWebdriver, you probably have this as a data structure: `List<WebElement>`.

Lists are part of the java.util.Collection framework and therefore it is not very hard to implement a sorting. Something like this could work, if list contains the `List<WebElement>` and the float values that you want to sort after are in an attribute called `toSortAfter`:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<WebElement>(){
@Override
public int compare(WebElement e1, WebElement e2){
    String fl1Str = e1.getAttribute("toSortAfter");
    String fl2Str = e2.getAttribute("toSortAfter");

    if (fl1Str != null && fl2Str != null){
       float f1 = Float.parseFloat(fl1Str);
       float f2 = Float.parseFloat(fl2Str);
       if (f1 < f2){
         return -1;
       }
       else if (f1 > f2) {
         return 1;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
});
```

I leave better handling of Exceptions to the interested reader... Also, note that I wrote this out of my head and without a Java-Compiler at hand. So there might be syntax or other mistakes.

*Note:*

Without the knowledge of the HMTL nodes you are collectiong it is not possible to help you any further. It might be, that the attribute is called differently, of that the float value is not an attribute altogether. If is it the content of the Elements, you can access this with WebElement.getText() method.

Comment: I want to put HTML here but Its size is increasing :(

Comment: Just grab the HTML of ONE of the nodes that you gather. Throw out child-nodes that are not relevant for the sorting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about selenium, My code is related to java. If your float number are strings like this (5.3 6.366), You can use below code:

```
String floatNumber = "5.3 6.366";
String[] numbers = floatNumber.split(" ");
Arrays.sort(numbers);
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```